# Computer is so slow after taking out the graphics card

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, integrated-graphics

I took graphics card out from my computer and it is working very slow. My computer has 8 GB RAM.

Any idea?

Help appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Sorry I didn't tell the reason why I took graphics card off. I needed it somewhere else.

Everything is slow. It used to take 15 - 20 seconds to boot up Windows, now it can take up to 3 minutes. Windows is installed on SSD. When I right click menu comes up in 2-3 seconds. Physical Memory usage is around 25%, but CPU usage is higher than normal. Sometimes it hits the 100% even if I don't do anything.

My computer is a desktop with:

Intel Motherboard 
Processor Intel 2 Quad CPU Q9300 2.50 GHz

I believe it has Intel G35 Express Chipset Family.

Comment: @pnuts that is the problem. I can't put it back. I want to use integrated graphics card.

Comment: @Dilshod - The downvote is because this is a vague "i have a problem" question without a single detail about the problem except "my computer is slow"

Comment: More information is required. How are you measuring "very slow' the lack of a GPU would not effect the speed of your computer. Furthermore why was it removed in the first place? Why do you want to use the integrated graphics card the graphic card you removed is faster then it. If you are trying to run graphic intensive games thats the reason its "slower" be specific about the problem you have.

Comment: Based on your update it soudns like your integrated graphics card is so slow that it doesn't even meet the requirements for Windows.  Did you uninstall the driver BEFORE you removed the graphics card?

Comment: "CPU usage is higher than normal. Sometimes it hits the 100%" -- What's reported as being the CPU hog? Does it behave the same way in Safe Mode? 15-20 seconds to boot Windows is NOT slow. ;)

Comment: What is your computer? The processor? The graphics chip? Motherboard?

Comment: @techie007 Sorry for my English. What I meant is it took 15-20 before. Now it is taking up to 3 mins.

Comment: @terdon It is desktop and it has Intel Motherboard, Processor Intel 2 Quad CPU Q9300  2.50 GHz. I believe it has Intel G35 Express Chipset Family.

Comment: When you press ctrl+alt+del and start the taskmanagr (possibly with show-process-from-all-users), what process does take up the CPU?

Comment: +1 for actually updating the question and making it more useful.

Comment: **Does it behave the same way in [Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/start-your-computer-in-safe-mode)?** :)  Have you done disk checks ([chkdsk](http://www.w7forums.com/use-chkdsk-check-disk-t448.html)) yet?

Comment: @techie007 In Safe Mode almost 5 mins I only see is mouse cursor. It took long time until the mouse came up.

Comment: Then it's probably not a driver problem.  To me it sounds like a bad disk and/or file-system.  Run a chkdsk and see if it reports anything wrong.

Comment: @techie007 I tried chkdsk and some other memory diagnostics with no luck.

Answer (score 4):

If the computer is especially slow while moving around windows or doing graphical stuff, maybe you do not have the correct video driver installed (assuming you still have a graphic card on the mainboard or that you have installed a new graphics card).

In any case, check under Start-Menu -> right-click Computer -> Manage -> Device Manager what video card is shown as installed and if it matches the card you have (and if it has the right driver).

Comment: I reinstalled the driver, but computer still working so slow.

Comment: It would help if you explained (maybe in your question) what exactly is slow.  Booting, graphics, games, loading a program, webbrowsing, etc.

Comment: did you see my update?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the PC was a Dell Inspiron N7110 it had an Nvidia's GeForce GT 525M graphics card with CUDA support. This allows for [GPU computing](http://www.nvidia.com/object/what-is-gpu-computing.html) where processing demand can be shared between CPU and graphics card. HDGraphics 3000 (the integrated graphics chip) does not have the same performance.

Comment: No this is not laptop. This is desktop computer.

Answer (score 0):

If CPU goes up to 100% even if you don't do anything, probably is looping or doing something that would slow down the computer.

Press Ctrl+Alt+Del, then choose Taskmanager.  And under Processes look which one is taking up most of the time.  Then post this here as update to your question, or google for the process to get an idea what it may be (maybe some sort of software that was relying on the graphics card).

Comment: System Idle Process is taking the most CPU. I think that is ok. There is nothing more that hogging the CPU.

Comment: Yes, that is okay indeed.